# Is it possible to concactenate a DataBound value with a constant string in XAML DataBinding?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

To bind a value to a `TextBlock` we use the following syntax to display an *<ItemName>* property of a bounded object.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" />
```

But is there a syntax to use the above tag to concatenate the constant string *'Item'* with the databounded property, in order display something like: ***Item*** <ItemName> in the `TextBlock`

Comment: why not just put a label before the textbox?

Comment: Yeah, actually this is what I am doing. But I was wondering if the above is still possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `StringFormat` in your binding, like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemName, StringFormat={}Item: {0}}"/>
```

That being said, it may cause some unexpected behavior when editing. For example, if the user edits only the item name (excluding the 'Item:' text), then when the TextBox loses focus, the string format will be displayed as "Item: Item: xyz", which is a bit weird. There might be a way to get around this issue, but nothing that springs to mind right now.

However, if the user clears the entire TextBox, then sets the name, then that's all fine and dandy.

Otherwise, it would probably be a better idea to use a `TextBlock` in front of your `TextBox`. Like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Item:" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0,0,6,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I made a mistake in the control, I was meaning `TextBlock` instead od `TextBox`, sorry for the confusion. I will edit my question accordingly. BTW thx for the warn concerning the `TextBox`